# Gradle multi project dependency no import

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

I would like to build a new project using an existing project as dependency. The following file structure is used:

```
projA
    -src
        -main
            -java
                -HelloWorld.java
    -build.gradle
    -settings.gradle
projB
    -src
        -main
            -java
                -Greeter.java
    -build.gradle
    -settings.gradle
```

Project in projA depends on the project in projB (HelloWorld uses Greeter). The settings.gradle of projB looks like this:

```
rootProject.name = 'projB'
```

The build.gradle is also pretty straight forward:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

The settings.gradle file of projA is set up to include projB like so:

```
rootProject.name = 'projA'
include ':projB'
project(':projB').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../projB')
```

Finally, the build.gradle of projA includes the project like so:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':projB')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Now, if I want to use Greeter in HelloWorld, I get an import error. Even if I rebuild the projA project. This is about as clean of a multi project as I can come up with. Why am I not able to use the classes of the specified dependency?

Comment: Do you have a root module above these two projects, or you have a flat structure?

Comment: Do you see dependency on projB in "Project Structure | Modules | Dependencies"?

Comment: This isn't a proper multi-project layout. Your `settings.gradle` for `projA` is hacky and in a proper setup, you would only have one `settings.gradle` file.

Comment: If there is only one settings.gradle, how would it be a multi-project archtitecture? It would be a multi-module architecture, right? I want to be able to separate the projects as much as possible. So the "flat structure" that M. Oguz Ozcan mentioned would be appealing

Comment: @user1111652, I think the flat structure, he means is to have just one module for all. Essentially, you have to have some sort of multi-module relationship to define to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You should have only one `settings.gradle` file, and it should be placed in the root project dir, like this:

```
projA/
    src/main/java/
        HelloWorld.java
    build.gradle
projB/
    src/main/java/
        Greeter.java
    build.gradle
settings.gradle
```

Your `settings.gradle` should look like this:

```
include 'projA'
include 'projB'
```

Also, you should use java packages in order to properly `import` the classes of the library project.

Comment: This does not seem like a multi project setup. Seems like a multi module setup. Project B already has its own settings file. Not going to delete it.

Comment: In gradle a multi-project build has one root project with a `settings.gradle`. According to the docs:
"A multi-project build in gradle consists of one root project, and one or more subprojects that may also have subprojects."
https://docs.gradle.org/4.3.1/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Comment: I think I will try a composite build for my project https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html